# SQL Server recursive CTE and paging

Tags: sql-server, select, paging, common-table-expression

I have this table

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[friend_blocked_list](
 [subdomain] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [un] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [friend] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [is_blocked] [bit] NOT NULL,
 [approved] [bit] NOT NULL)
```

where i select data from it with below query. Select query combines users that added user as friend and users that have been added as friend by user

```
declare @un varchar(50), @subdomain varchar(50)

set @un='user2';
set @subdomain ='test.domain.com';

WITH FRIENDS as
(
  SELECT friend
  FROM friend_blocked_list
  WHERE un=@un and subdomain=@subdomain and approved=1 and is_blocked=0

  UNION ALL

  SELECT un as friend
  FROM friend_blocked_list
  WHERE friend=@un and subdomain=@subdomain and approved=1 and is_blocked=0
)
select friend from FRIENDS group by FRIENDS.friend order by FRIENDS.friend asc
```

It works fine with small amout of data but i want to be able to do a paging on the server side in order to reduce load. I am trying to combine it with my paging sp below

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[Paging]
    @subdomain varchar(50),
    @un varchar(50),
    @PageNumber int,
    @PageSize int
AS
BEGIN
   --paging
   DECLARE @FirstRow INT,@LastRow INT,@RowCount INT,@PageCount INT

   --find recordcount and pages
   SELECT @RowCount = COUNT(*), @PageCount = COUNT(*) / @PageSize 
   FROM friend_blocked_list 
   WHERE subdomain=@subdomain AND un=@un AND approved=1 AND is_blocked=0;

   --- calculate pages    
   IF @RowCount % @PageSize != 0 SET @PageCount = @PageCount + 1 
   IF @PageNumber < 1 SET @PageNumber = 1 
   IF @PageNumber > @PageCount SET @PageNumber = @PageCount 

   SELECT 
        CurrentPage = @PageNumber, 
        TotalPages = @PageCount, 
        TotalRows = @RowCount 

   -- mora calculation
   SELECT @FirstRow = ( @PageNumber - 1) * @PageSize + 1,
          @LastRow = (@PageNumber - 1) * @PageSize + @PageSize ;

   WITH MyTopics  AS
   (
      SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by un asc) AS RowNumber
      FROM friend_blocked_list 
      WHERE subdomain=@subdomain AND un=@un AND approved=1 AND is_blocked=0
   )
   SELECT *
   FROM MyTopics
   WHERE RowNumber BETWEEN @FirstRow AND @LastRow
   ORDER BY RowNumber ASC;
end
```

But as always i am having trouble :). Main problem is the `UNION ALL` in my query. It prevents me using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your procedure updated for paging:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Paging]
  @subdomain varchar(50),
  @un varchar(50),
  @PageNumber int,
  @PageSize int
AS

  DECLARE @start_row int
  DECLARE @end_row int

  SET @end_row = @PageNumber * @PageSize
  SET @start_row = @end_row - (@PageSize - 1)

BEGIN

  WITH FRIENDS AS (
    SELECT t.friend
      FROM FRIEND_BLOCKED_LIST t
     WHERE t.un = @un 
       AND t.subdomain = @subdomain 
       AND t.approved = 1 
       AND t.is_blocked = 0
   UNION ALL
    SELECT t.un as friend
      FROM FRIEND_BLOCKED_LIST t
     WHERE t.friend = @un 
       AND t.subdomain = @subdomain 
       AND t.approved = 1 
       AND t.is_blocked = 0)
SELECT t.friend
  FROM (SELECT f.friend,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY f.friend) AS rownum
          FROM FRIENDS f
      GROUP BY f.friend) t
 WHERE t.rownum BETWEEN @start_row AND @end_row

END
```

It might be possible to change the query to use one CTE if you could provide more information on the `FRIEND_BLOCKED_LIST` table.  The `UNION` of two queries with identical `WHERE` clauses while differentiating between two columns makes me wonder if it couldn't be written better.  Could the FRIENDS CTE be rewritten as:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t.un, t.friend) as friend
  FROM FRIEND_BLOCKED_LIST t
 WHERE @un = COALESCE(t.un, t.friend)
   AND t.subdomain = @subdomain 
   AND t.approved = 1 
   AND t.is_blocked = 0
```

Comment: What sort of info would you need on FRIEND_BLOCKED_LIST table?

Comment: also in second select after union all it should be  

WHERE t.friend= @un 

istead of

 WHERE t.un = @un 


so they are not identical queries

Comment: Column list if it's not terribly long, and what your logic is for the UNION on FRIEND_BLOCKED_LIST.  The query as is, looks like it would return FRIEND_BLOCKED_LIST.friend and FRIEND_BLOCKED_LIST.un for the same person(?).  It's not clear what is going on in the table.

Comment: Fixed the 2nd part of the UNION, sorry for my typo.

Comment: i am trying to select users that (say) usera have as friend and users that have usera as friend

Comment: SELECT COALESCE(t.un, t.friend) as friend  FROM FRIEND_BLOCKED_LIST t WHERE @un = COALESCE(t.un, t.friend)   AND t.subdomain = @subdomain    AND t.approved = 1    AND t.is_blocked = 0

doesn;t return desired result

Comment: would it be easier with temp table?

Comment: No, a CTE is a temp table under the covers.  I understand what you want to get from the database, but I don't have enough information to be able to craft a better query for you.

Comment: what do you need to know about table? what sort of data in it?

Answer (score 0):

Apply the row number to the list you want to return:

```
WITH FRIENDS as
(
SELECT friend
  FROM friend_blocked_list
  WHERE un=@un and subdomain=@subdomain and approved=1 and is_blocked=0
UNION ALL
SELECT un as friend
  FROM friend_blocked_list
  WHERE friend=@un and subdomain=@subdomain and approved=1 and is_blocked=0 )
, recursive_friends as  (
select friend 
 , row_number() over (order by friend asc) as rn
from FRIENDS )
select friend 
  from recursive_friends
  where rn between @firstRow and @lastRow
  order by FRIENDS.friend asc;
```

Comment: , recursive_friends as  (select friend  , row_number() over (order by friend asc) as rnfrom FRIENDS ) doesn't seem to be right